# C++ templates implicitly use

Tags: c++, function, templates, arguments, explicit

I have defined such function:

```
template<typename T>
void SwapMe(T *first, T *second)
{
    T tmp = *first;
    *first = *second;
    *second = tmp;
}
```

Then using it like so:

```
SwapMe(&data[i], &data[j]);
```

As you see, I'm not using explicitly `SwapMe<T>(...);` but it does work!
Why C++ standard allows to avoid explicitly specifying the type of the arguments ?

Comment: STL includes this as part of [his series](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/C9-Lectures-Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-/Stephan-T-Lavavej-Core-C-2-of-n).

Comment: Oleg, this is called Template argument deduction. I'd suggest you take a look at some good [C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) for starters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The necessary `T` can be ***deduced*** from the type of `*first`.

Explicitly specifying by programmer is only necessary if the deduction cannot be automatically made by the compiler.

This (seemingly simple but actually quite involved) phenomenon is known as [Argument Dependent Name Lookup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument-dependent_name_lookup) or Koenig lookup, named after its inventor [Andrew Koenig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Koenig_%28programmer%29).